# Displaying data from two models in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models with respective controllers and views: `Profile` and `Comment`.

The entire view (whole webpage) of my application is in the `Profile` `show.html.erb`. On this page, the user should be able to create a comment, which `belongs_to` a `Profile`.

How can this be accomplished without having to navigate to the standard `/comments/new` page?

**Edit:**
After following the rails guide, I implemented:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@profile, @profile.comment.build], html: {class: "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :description, label: false, placeholder: 'Create an comment', input_html: { class: "span4" } %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-small'%>

<% end %>
```

CommentController

```
 def create
  @profile = profile.find(params[:profile_id])
  @comment = @profile.comments.create(params[:comment])
  redirect_to profile_path(@profile)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `comment' for #<Profile:
```

**Fixed:** In the build statement, comments needed to be plural

```
@profile.comments.build
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller

Comment: Please see above error

Comment: You forgot an `s` at comment in your form declaration: `<%= simple_form_for([@profile, @profile.comments.build]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add the comment form code into profile#show. Then in the show action of profile_controller do something like:

```
def show
 @comment = Comment.new
end
```

And in the comments controller add:

```
def create
 @comment = Comment.create(params[:comment])
end
```

Comment: I believe the first method you meant to say was in the new action, instead of the show action.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider saving the form and updating the page using AJAX calls and possibly something like [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/). So in profiles/show.html.erb, make a regular (separate) form just for posting comments. Use jQuery or something like it to post the form via AJAX to /comments, so it goes the create action in your comments controller. Have that controller return a JSON response, that will either be the saved comment, or a hash of error messages that looks something like {:fieldname => 'too long'}.

On the client, parse the json response and either display the saved comment, or display the error message explaining why it couldn't be saved. You can do all this in plain jQuery, but adding something like Knockout will make it all a bit simpler.